# Удаление элементов списка RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Ситуация такая, есть список (RecyclerView), нужно реализовать удаление элементов из списка при помощи CheckBox. То есть, есть нормальный режим и режим удаления. Когда один элемент в layout меняется на другой элемент (CheckBox). Данный переход я решил добавлением if() и установки видимости/невидимости этим элементам.

Следующая проблема с RecyclerView который умеет переиспользовать контейнеры что чревато выделениями там где они  не нужны. Так же это будет проблемой при сборе элементов которые нужно удалять. На данный момент я вижу только одно решение, хранить данный флаг в объекте элемента списка. Возможно есть инное решение или кто знает как это верно делается?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас два варианта:

1. Как Вы и сами предположили - хранить значение флага в объекте элемента списка.
2. Создать коллекцию где вы будете хранить ИДишники "чекнутых" элементов.

Comment: Я бы предложил третий. Когда вы создаете адаптер обернуть свои объекты в объект а-ля Selectable, где всего два поля - одно булево isSelected и второе - содержащее указанный объект. И везде в адаптере работать именно с таким объектом

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, не совсем вас понял, но идея интересная. Можно по подробнее?!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vyhPHaAZ  вот такой объект. При создании адаптера список ваших объектов превращаем в список вот таких объектов и работаем с ними до тех пор, пока не придется выдать выделенные объекты за пределы адаптера или списка

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, идея хорошая, но как-то немного запутанная. Она прекрасная если тебе всегда нужно держать те или инные елементы выделенными, но вот на сколько она целесообразна в моей задаче.